# NetSuite Suitelet to include a client-side script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to add a client script to a Suitelet in order to do some DOM actions, I have found adding libraries but that is server side, I need to add a client-side script to the page. I am checking all the checkboxes or not in a list ob checkboxes from a button. Any help with this would be great thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are rendering an `nlobjForm` or `N/serverWidget.Form`...

In SuiteScript 1.0:

```js
form.setScript(clientScriptId); // see docs for nlobjForm#setScript
```

In SuiteScript 2.0:

```js
form.clientScriptModulePath = "path/to/client/script.js";
// see docs for N/serverWidget.Form
```

Comment: Which scriptid is that? is that for a script record? internal id from the file? sorry if I'm dim, thanks for your help

Comment: The `clientScriptId` would be the internal ID of the Script record for your Client Script, so it should be something like `customscript_blah`; note that you *do not* need to deploy your Client Script. The path for the 2.0 version is relative to the root of the File Cabinet I believe.